# Rails 3.2 has_secure_password fails silently when deployed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I upgraded the authentication in my application to use Rails 3.1's has_secure_password facility. In the process, I created a page to allow users to change their passwords. I tested it and it works on my development machine, both in development and production environments.

When I deployed the application to Heroku, I went to try it and it seemed to work, except when I logged out and logged back in, my password was unchanged. I tried changing the password manually in the console and that works fine. If I try to enter different text for the password and confirmation, it shows the validation it is supposed to, which means the password is getting sent to the app correctly.

Here is the relevant change to my controller: https://github.com/mjm/sis-lunch/commit/930ced467a0e23ad48f4497999183112c5f846b1#diff-2

Is there something I'm missing? What could be wrong with it in production on Heroku that could cause this to silently fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. I deployed the app to Heroku, then ran the migrations. The app was not fully aware of the new password_digest column, but new consoles were, so they worked fine. Restarting the app using `heroku restart` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are testing it on your development machine, since PeopleControllerTest is empty, but the password field is protected against mass assignment.  It *shouldn't* work in PeopleController the way it is written.  (that's a good thing!)

You will need to explicitly call **Person#password=** in your controller.

The relevant Rails source code for [ActiveModel::SecurePassword](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/826a85069627060c11baf932423702b1228dd4df/activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb) can show you exactly what happens when you use has_secure_password.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The code only makes password_digest protected, not password, and I was able to log in to the production console and assign those properties via attributes=.

Comment: Ah nope, you're right. I overlooked the attr_accessible when I compared my notes earlier.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: I answered my own question actually, turns out I just had to restart the app after doing the migrations.